# Opening a print preview tab in my application and it resizes when I ctrl +/- the original application

Tags: tabs, zooming, microsoft-edge

I am working on an application that has a print preview page. When the user goes to open this print preview page it opens up on a separate tab. When the user zooms in or out of the main application tab the print preview tab duplicates the zoom in/out. This is specifically an issue on the Microsoft Edge browser. Looking for a solution to make the zoom/in out functionality behave independently when different tabs are opened in the app.

Comment: please show code to let others know how to help better

Comment: Please inform us which exact version of the Edge browser you are using for making the test? Does it work properly on other browsers? Which kind of application it is? Does it use the browser inbuilt print preview? I try to check the print preview functionality of the Edge legacy and Edge Chromium browser but I am not able to produce the said issue with it. If possible then please try to provide a code sample or detailed steps to test the issue. It can really help us to understand the issue in a better way.